# Подсветка синтаксиса, как подсветить то, что находится в кавычках?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qsyntaxhighlighter

Мой код:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QSyntaxHighlighter, QTextCharFormat, QFont, QPainter, QColor, QPaintEngine

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRegularExpression


class MyHighlighter(QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        char_format = QTextCharFormat(); char_format.setForeground(QColor(100, 90, 32)) #Q text format

        expression = QRegularExpression(r"\b(print)\b")
        _001 = expression.globalMatch(text)
        while _001.hasNext():
            match = _001.next()
            self.setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), char_format)
            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = QTextEdit()
    mw.setText("")

    highlighter = MyHighlighter(mw.document())

    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Так как сделать подсветку в кавычках?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант.

```
import sys
import re
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Highlighter(QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._mapping = {}

    def add_mapping(self, pattern, pattern_format):
        self._mapping[pattern] = pattern_format

    def highlightBlock(self, text_block):
        for pattern, fmt in self._mapping.items():
            for match in re.finditer(pattern, text_block):
                start, end = match.span()
                self.setFormat(start, end-start, fmt)


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet('QWidget {font-size: 20px;}')

        self.highlighter = Highlighter()

        self.setUpEditor()
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.editor)

    def setUpEditor(self):
        class_format = QTextCharFormat()
        class_format.setForeground(Qt.blue)
        class_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
        pattern = r'^\s*class\s+\w+\(.*$'
        self.highlighter.add_mapping(pattern, class_format)

        function_format = QTextCharFormat()
        function_format.setForeground(Qt.red)
        function_format.setFontItalic(True)
        pattern = r'^\s*def\s+\w+\s*\(.*\)\s*:\s*$'
        self.highlighter.add_mapping(pattern, function_format)        

        comment_format = QTextCharFormat()
        comment_format.setBackground(QColor("#ADFF2F"))
        pattern = r"\"[^\"]*\""  
        self.highlighter.add_mapping(pattern, comment_format)
        
        comment_format = QTextCharFormat()
        comment_format.setBackground(QColor("#ADFF2F"))
        pattern = r"'[^\']*\'"                             
        self.highlighter.add_mapping(pattern, comment_format)        

        self.editor = QPlainTextEdit()
        font = QFontDatabase.systemFont(QFontDatabase.FixedFont)
        self.editor.setFont(font)

        self.highlighter.setDocument(self.editor.document())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyApp()
    w.resize(800, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @FreOver что не так?

Comment: всё прекрасно просто не заходил в сеть